# Construct an advanced slice from string in Python/Numpy

Tags: python-3.x, numpy

Suppose I have a CLI and would like to construct a slice from the CLI, where the CLI user just inputs a range string.

```
r = '1:4:2'
axis = '2'
```

And I have a way of slicing this as follows:

```
arr = np.zeros((10,10,10))

sliced_arr = eval("arr["+','.join([':',':',r])+"]")
```

Question: is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Yes. Not using `eval` is just about always better.

Comment: is `axis` ever (meant to be) used?

Comment: @norok2 yeah, in my full code it is used.  I didn't bother because this is the minimal representation.  It just is there to imply that it is part of a bigger function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one using `r` and `axis` as input arguments -

```
indexer = [slice(None)]*arr.ndim
indexer[int(axis)] = slice(*map(int,r.split(':')))
out = arr[tuple(indexer)]
```

Generalizing to handle to any generic indexing string notation in `r`, it would be -

```
ax = int(axis)
indexer = [slice(None)]*arr.ndim
o = np.array([0,arr.shape[ax],1])
v = np.array(r.split(':'))
v = np.r_[v,['']*(len(o)-len(v))]
indexer[ax] = slice(*np.where(v=='',o,v).astype(int))
out = arr[tuple(indexer)]
```

Comment: one reason I went with `eval` is in case someone did something clever like "`::-1`": the eval will always work exactly like brackets.  I did look at slice, but it seemed like it would not handle this case well.  Is that wrong?

Comment: @donlan Edited to handle generic string notations in `r`.

Answer (score 1):

You could build a [slice](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#slice) object from the string, and then use [numpy.s_](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.s_.html):

```
import numpy as np

r = '1:4:2'
arr = np.zeros((10,10,10))

s = slice(*map(int, r.split(":")))
print(s)

sliced_arr = arr[np.s_[:, :, s]]
```

**Output**

```
slice(1, 4, 2)
```

Comment: I think OP wants to use that slice only for the one axis

Comment: Perhaps, but the string passed to `eval()` is, indeed, `'arr[:,:,1:4:2]'` which would not be strictly equivalent to this solution.

Comment: @norok2 You are right, modified the answer to match the output of the `eval()`

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like this, which also supports negative `index`s:

```py
import numpy as np


def str2slicing(
        slice_str: str,
        index: int,
        n_dim: int):
    assert(-n_dim <= index < n_dim)
    index %= n_dim
    return tuple(
        slice(*map(int, slice_str.split(':'))) if i == index else slice(None)
        for i in range(n_dim))


arr = np.random.randint(1, 100, (10, 10, 10))
sliced_arr = arr[str2slicing('1:4:2', int('2'), arr.ndim)]
print(sliced_arr.shape)
# (10, 10, 2)
```

(Note that this is pretty much an [extension](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59200103/5218354) / [variation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59200154/5218354) of the other answers: the juice is pretty much this `slice(*map(int, slice_str.split(':')))`).